# Проблема с chat_invite_user_by_link (объект messages)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, php7

Я решил обратиться к вам за помощью, ибо сам не понимаю как с этим бороться. У меня есть паблик-бот, который состоит в беседе, имеет полный доступ к переписке, а также права администратора. Всё идеально работает, кроме отправки сообщения при вступлении в беседу по ссылке. Я думал, что проблема в коде: создаю новую беседу, выдаю те же права и всё работает. Я недоумеваю, что может быть тому причиной. Я буду рад услышать ваши догадки по этому поводу

Comment: Может вы неправильно получаете сам 'action'? Прикрепите код, мы мысли читать не умеем)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь за беспокойство. Проблема была в том, что участок кода находился не в том блоке. Код действительно объемный и я легко упустил такую деталь